# Do I need a wait time for setting a new folder vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I am using the following code:

```
Set StorageFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set StorageFolder = StorageFileSystem.GetFolder(PathToStorageFiles)
msgBox "Set folders for Storage"
for each Storagefile in StorageFolder.Files     'get the creation time of the oldest recording
msgBox "DateCreated: " & Storagefile.DateCreated & vbCrLf & "EarylDateTime: " & earlyDateTime & vbCrLf & "DateTime to compare: " & dateadd("h" ,-6, Now)
     if Storagefile.DateCreated < dateadd("h" ,-6, Now) then
        earlyDateTime = Storagefile.DateCreated
 end if
next
```

I have used this before without problem, even in the program that this is in. However this time it never seems to do anything. The folder has over 130,000 files in it (391GB). I don't know if I should include a delay so that the program can emumerate them or if there is some other problem that I just don't see. 
Any ideas? I'm using VBS, the msgBox between the 2 set statements and the for loop works, but the one between the opening of the for loop and the if statement does not.

Comment: What is the value of `PathToStorageFiles`? Does `For Each f In StorageFolder.Files : WScript.Echo f.Name : Next` list the files? Note: run the script with `cscript.exe`, otherwise you'll have to confirm 130,000 popup messages. For the same reason I'd *strongly* recommend removing the `MsgBox` inside the loop.

Comment: PathToStorageFiles is the file path to the server where the files are being housed.I did find several flaws in my logic so I'm not using the above code any longer. I'll be posting what I got to work in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I got to work:

```
Option Explicit
Dim LocalStorage, NewLocalStorage, recentFile, objFSO, colFiles, objFolder, file, OldestDate, strOldestDate, fso, ts, objFile
LocalStorage = "D:\BlueIris\Storage"
NewLocalStorage = "D:\BlueIris\New"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(NewLocalStorage)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each file in colFiles
  If recentFile = "" Then
    recentFile = file.DateCreated
  ElseIf file.DateCreated > recentFile Then
    recentFile = file.DateCreated
  End If
Next
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(LocalStorage)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
OldestDate = Now

For Each objFile in colFiles
    if objFile.DateCreated < OldestDate Then
        OldestDate = objFile.DateCreated
        strOldestDate = objFile.DateCreated
    End if
Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile ("C:\DVRInfo.txt", true)
ts.writeline recentFile
ts.writeline strOldestDate
ts.close
```

I run this on the actual server so that it runs a lot faster than the original code I attempted. Let me know if you still flaws in this please, I want to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks

EDIT:
New code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim LocalStorage, NewLocalStorage, recentFile, objFSO, colFiles, objFolder, file, OldestDate, strOldestDate, fso, ts, objFile
LocalStorage = "D:\BlueIris\Storage"
NewLocalStorage = "D:\BlueIris\New"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(NewLocalStorage)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
Set recentFile = 0
For Each file in colFiles
  If file.DateCreated > recentFile Then
    recentFile = file.DateCreated
  End If
Next
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(LocalStorage)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
OldestDate = Now
For Each objFile in colFiles
    if objFile.DateCreated < OldestDate Then
        OldestDate = objFile.DateCreated
        strOldestDate = objFile.DateCreated
    End if
Next
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile ("C:\DVRInfo.txt", true)
ts.writeline recentFile
ts.writeline strOldestDate
ts.close
```

Comment: There are improvements you can do. See the UPDATE section on my ans.

Comment: Change `ts.writeline strOldestDate` to `ts.writeline OldestDate`, and remove the `strOldestDate = objFile.DateCreated` and good to go. You could also put wait command on 2nd goal until the 1st goal has written the file.

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't even notice the two different variables doing the same thing. This is someone else's code that didn't work and I was left to fix it when he left the company. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying the codes in the For loop doesn't seem to work? It seems not work if the folder does not have any files in it. So check the value of `PathToStorageFiles`.

Your logic of getting the **oldest recording creation time** is flawed - any time that is 6 hours before `Now` is treated as oldest and set to earlyDateTime.

Try this code below, with sample output:

```
PathToStorageFiles = "C:\Test" ' <=- Change this!
Set StorageFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set StorageFolder = StorageFileSystem.GetFolder(PathToStorageFiles)
sOldestFile = "" ' Stores the full name of the file
earlyDateTime = dateadd("h" ,-6, Now) ' Assuming 6 hours before script started is oldest (it can be just Now)
wscript.echo StorageFolder.Files.Count & " files in the folder " & PathToStorageFiles
for each Storagefile in StorageFolder.Files     'get the creation time of the oldest recording
    if Storagefile.DateCreated < earlyDateTime then
        sOldestFile = Storagefile.Path
        earlyDateTime = Storagefile.DateCreated
        wscript.echo "earlyDateTime changed to " & earlyDateTime & " | " & sOldestFile
    end if
next
wscript.echo vbCrLf & "Oldest file: " & sOldestFile & vbCrLf & "Created on: " & earlyDateTime
```

[image: cscript Output]

On a side note, you should modify this to process sub folders too, then move files into folders. 130,000 files in a single folder is a mess!

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your posted solution, there are improvements you can do.

First, use 1 FileSystemObject.

Then the `recentFile` in the for loop. You should set it to zero first, rather than 2 comparisons. Having said that, you have the opportunity to time the differences.

```
recentFile = 0
For Each file in colFiles
  If file.DateCreated > recentFile Then
    recentFile = file.DateCreated
  End If
Next
```

Lastly, if the D: on the server is a NAS, then you can split the code into 2 parts - one search for most recent, the other for oldest. Then use batch file `start cscript.exe //nologo <script#.vbs>` method to start them in 2 processes. This you need 2 txt files for output.

If there is only 1 folder to get the latest & oldest file, it can be in 1 for loop.

Comment: I agree that having that many files in a single folder is a mess, but it's not up to me to decide if they should be sorted. I did notice the flaw in my logic, that and it takes a really long time.I did find a way to do it and I'll post it as an answer in a minute.

Comment: Okay, I can't use two different text file outputs I need it to be only one output (I use it in another program). However I did try changing my code some so that now it is this: